# PHP foreach inside foreach fills array with entry from iteration before

Tags: php, arrays

So i get data from an api and want to save the results in an array. But the results have some arrays inside them and that data i want to iterate and add to an array.

It works to iterate the results and also the array of the results, but when i want to save the data inside a DB e.g. the first of the inner array data get saved inside the parent result perfectly, but the second entry gets the data of the first inner array and the second one and the third gets the first and second and so on. I think i do something wrong with the loops or have to clear the array after each iteration, but then i only get the last entry of the inner array in the end...

So it looks like this:

```php
foreach($results as $result) {
  // add data e.g. inside DB
  foreach($result->inner as $inner) {
    $inner_fields[] = [
      'field_2312312' => $inner->name,
      'field_3345343' => $inner->desc
    ];
    //add data from inner_fields inside the new db entry
  }
}
```

Why is the data from the first iteration of $inner also saved in the second iteration data?

Comment: Not sure with the code provided but maybe after `foreach($results as $result) {` do `$inner_fields = [];`.  You need to show what _//add data from inner_fields inside the new db entry_ actually is.

Comment: Show sample of data in and data out... would be helpful! - as in your $results json or whatever... and your output.

Comment: @AbraCadaver actually thats the solution! I added the init of the array inside the outside-loop and now everything is behaving correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AbraCadaver Maybe you can post this as an answer so i can mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell without the code provided, as there's no telling what your using in *//add data from inner_fields inside the new db entry*.  However, if you're using the array there then you do need to reset/empty it:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $inner_fields = [];

    foreach($result->inner as $inner) {
        $inner_fields[] = ['field_2312312' => $inner->name,
                           'field_3345343' => $inner->desc
                          ];
        //add data from inner_fields inside the new db entry
    }
}
```

Comment: As said in the comments, that is the solution i needed. I didnt provide the exact code because it is very specific to the content management system i am using (adding the DB entries) but in short: I have some fields on every db entry that is made by the outer loop which get filled with the inner loop. I knew it was an issue with the loops, so i stripped the code above down to it. Thank you so much!